# What does the bottom part of 夢 mean, right under the 3 squares?

Tags: kanji

I've been looking all over for the response but in 夢(dream) what does the bottom part right below the three little squares mean or say??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [This page](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E5%A4%A2) says it's a bed or a sleeping person.
- [This page](http://www.slownet.ne.jp/sns/area/culture/reading/kodai/201002031622-2000001.html) says it's a 被せ物 (cover, veil).

As for the uppermost part (⺾), some say [it's grass](https://okjiten.jp/kanji172.html#a), some say [it's horns of a sheep](http://www.slownet.ne.jp/sns/area/culture/reading/kodai/201002031622-2000001.html), some say [it's eyelash](http://lcprichi.hkbu.edu.hk/search/show_word.php?id=568). The pages I've seen so far consistently say that the "squares" (⺫) part refers to 目 (eye).

It's often very difficult or impossible to determine the etymology of each kanji. We have [the shapes of some old variants of this kanji](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E5%A4%A2), but people today can only speculate it's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

「夢{む}」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*C.məŋ-s/**) is decomposed into semantic「夕」(*evening*). The other part of the character is a phonetic hint.

> The other part of the character is
>
> <kbd>[image]</kbd>
>
> with slightly altered strokes (such that the bottom appears as「冖」). The functionality of this part derives from a graphically reduced form of「蔑{めち}」(**/*mˤet/**). To see the graphical connection, remove「戈」from「蔑」.
>
> This part is a depiction of a person「儿・人」with their head (*eyes*「目」and *eyebrows*「卝」) exaggerated. It (and by extension「夢」) does not contain *grass*「⺾」or *cover*「冖」, which are graphical coincidences in the modern Japanese form.
>
> 「{{zh-HK:夢}}」normally appears with「卝」in Traditional Chinese, not「⺾」.

---

For reference, character evolution sequence:

- Obsolete shape:

  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]
  [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)・690
  [合集32212](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32212&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
  [image]</kbd>

  The character on the left is, component-wise, equivalent to the character on the right minus「宀」and「夕」. The left-hand-side component,「爿{しょう}」, is a picture of a bed, and this word is now written as「床{しょう}」. The whole character is a picture of a person with an exaggerated head sleeping on a bed.
- Modern character:

  <kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
  兵器文字
  [image]
  卅四年頓丘命戈</kbd>
  　<kbd>戰國・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)・[帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
  [image]
  甲篇・1.69
  長沙子彈庫楚帛書</kbd><kbd>今
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)